# Optimize a function in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I need to optimize this function:

```
10 ** 9 / n * 9 * 10 **6 + 1 / 2 * n * 1 / 25 * 180.
```

This is what I tried in Python, but I get the error "Float Division By Zero" and I don't understand why :(. Can you help me with that?

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

def minimF(n):
    return (float)(10 ** 9 / n * 9 * 10 **6 + 1 / 2 * n * 1 / 25 * 180)

def function(N, ca, cs,theta):
    C0_Min = minimize_scalar(minimF)
    print(C0_Min)
function(10**9,9*10**6,1/25,180)
```

Comment: I think you need to provide boundaries, optimization algorithm guessed `0` to be good starting point for optimization of `n` variable and failed at start

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that n starts off as zero, meaning that `2 * n * 1` is equal to 0, which provides the error as that equation during the first iteration is equal to `1000000000/ 1.0/0.0/ 4500`, which provides the `float division by zero` error. if you could provide some more context as to what the code is supposed to do, that would help.

Comment: Hi, I need to find out the optimal value for n in the given function. This operation was originally done in maple and now I have to redo it in Python . 
The nonlinear function given is: N/n*ca + 1/2 * cs * n * theta, where N = 10^9 , ca = 9 * 10 ^ 6, cs = 1/25 and theta is 180; 
Nonlinear optimization: [min ( n > 0 )] C(n) = N/n * ca+1/2*n*cs*theta

. Maple solution : 
N:=1000000000; theta:= 180; ca := 9000000; cs := 1/25
minimize(N*ca/n+(1/2)*n*cs*theta)

.From this I get that the optimal value of n is 4.999 * 10^7